# Bitrix 24 (Selfhosted), how to develop?

Tags: bitrix

I have some questions to someone that had been using **bitrix24 framework**, currently in the company where i'm working has bought bitrix 24 framework and i need to make some customization to the code or part of it, I want to add dependents fields (combo or select) where the people can **choose the x district** and with ajax **populate the Neighborhood (other select field)**, i found the bitrix24 tutorial but seriously those tutorials are too basic they dont explain very well how to customize or add some scripts ...

The turorial is [here](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=68&LESSON_ID=6149&LESSON_PATH=5936.6148.6149)

here is a image to explain better [Bitrix custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02dfw.png)

Thanks you so much in advance, i will apreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

I have same problems like you (instructions for Bitrix are very basic).

Best way is that you turn on performance tab inside Bitrix:

Example:

[performance Bitrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VFim.png)

You will see red squares inside Bitrix now.
Example:

[Red squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKHJF.png)

Inside red squares you will have: ''bitrix:crm.field_multi.edit'' this code is located inside  /www/bitrix/components/bitrix/crm.field_multi.edit

Be careful with modification. If you will modifications code inside /www/bitrix/components/bitrix you will lost your modification after you will update Bitrix.

You must copy entire component and create new component call.